# How many Pokemons can be in one gym?

Tags: pokemon-go

I was wondering how many Pokemons a single gym can hold because it doesn't let me put my Pokemon into the gym.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the Gym level. 
For instance a Gym level 3 can have 3 Pokemon guarding it. Also on the top, just bellow the levle you can see dots and a crown. If there are empty dots, you can put your pokemon in.

Comment: It's also worth noting that to unlock extra gym slots, you need to train at that gym to raise it's prestige.

Answer (score 1):

The gym has a reputation level.
1 pokemon per level(Max level is 10). So if you want the max you can have up to 10 pokemon (of course 1 slot per trainer).